# How to run ISOLATED Azure Function app on a different port in Visual Studio 2019 & .NET 5 Isolated

Tags: azure-functions, .net-5

There are many answers and articles on how to change a port for Azure Function in-process, but I cannot find a way to change a port on .NET Isolated.

I tried putting host start --port XXXX -nodeDebugPort XXXX in the application argument, I tried --pause-on-error --port XXX without host start, I tried start --port XXX and adding "Host": { "LocalHttpPort": 7072 } to local.settings.json, but none of them are working.

Comment: The link you gave me runs the function but the VS debugger fails to attach with the process and therefore I cannot debug the application, and I need to debug the code.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is looking for vs 2022 since the menu is different.

## Visual Studio 2022

- Right-click **Function > Properties > Debug > General**
- Open debug launch profiles UI
- Add a command line argument (--port 7072)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that with Visual Studio 2022, the local configuration file is again properly read:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7074,
    "CORS": "*"
  }
}
```

Leads to properly running the function under **.NET 5** on port 7074

```
 http://localhost:7074/api
```